# SQL Server 2008 - How fast are table joins across databases (same server) vs. tables in the same database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We're customizing a CMS that has a few hundred tables in it. We are considering moving our custom tables to a separate database on the same server.

Should we expect much of a slow down in SQL Server? There will be many multi-join stored procedures joining data across the CMS database and our custom database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

should not make an impact......however you can also use a [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx) instead and place all your tables under that schema in the same database. This way all your stuff will be logically grouped together

Comment: ...if only we could browse through different schemas in a collapse/expand kinda manner in SSMS...

Comment: @Denis you can filter by schema in SSMS - I do all the time.

Comment: true, but filter <> hierarchical browsing; it would be nice if SSMS did a tree view for database/Tables/Schema ->Tablelist instead of database/Tables ->Schema.Tablelist

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends if the filegroups are the different.  If they are the different, you might see the queries speed up (see SQLMenace's comment below).

My current place of employment has 3 databases that all communicate with each other on the same server, and there is no noticeable lag.

Comment: if they are on different filegroups and the filegroups are on different drives then that should be faster because you can read from 2 drives at the same time with 2 CPUs...This is why non clustered indexes are placed on different drives than the tables/clustered indexes

Comment: Yep, thanks SQLMenace.  I completely over-thought that one, and convinced myself of the opposite.  I edited my answer.